# CI_model not catching POSTed JSON data correctly

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, codeigniter

After tons of coding, I feel like I am finally wrapping my head around AJAX, JSON, and CI to a degree.

However, I feel I have hit one final snag.  Below is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="structures">
    <h1>Build</h1>
    <form name="buildForm" id="buildForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/ajax/index/">
        <select name="buildID" class="buildClass">
        <option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Build a Structure</option>
<?php foreach ($structures as $structure_info): ?>
    <option name='<?php echo $structure_info['str_name'] ?>' value='<?php echo $structure_info['str_id'] ?>' data-icon='<?php echo $structure_info['str_imageloc'] ?>' data-html-text='<?php echo $structure_info['str_name'] ?><i>
        <?php echo $structure_info['timebuildmins'] ?> minutes<br><?php echo $structure_info['buy_gold'] ?> gold</i>'><?php echo $structure_info['str_name'] ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
        <div id="buildSubmit">
            <input id ="btnSubmit" class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here I am simply building my form.

**AJAX/JS**

```
$(function(){
    $("#buildForm").click(function(e, buildID){
        e.preventDefault();
        var frm = $(document.buildForm);
        var dat = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
        alert("I am about to POST this:\n\n" + dat);
        $.post(
            frm.attr("action"),
            dat,        
        function(response) 
        {  
            alert(response);
        }  
    );
});
});
```

**Model Function**

```
public function insert_build()
   {    
      $str_id = $this->input->post(dat);
      print_r($str_id);
   }
```

I created a new controller class extension "Ajax" and function "index" This simply calls my model "insert_build." It was my workaround to take the .js file off the page and keep it in the header.

Anyway.  When I hit the submit button, it successfully alerts the JSON output.  Though after it is passed to the controller->model, it doesn't seem to catch anywhere. I assume I'm doing it wrong, but can not figure out what.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not sure if it's just how you pasted it into SO, but "$this->input->post(dat)" should be "$this->input->post('dat')"

Comment: A small hint that might help you in the future. Give console.log a try instead of alerts. It just keeps things more elegant ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a couple things here.

After `var frm = $(document.buildForm);` try alerting it's action value

```
alert(frm.attr("action"));
```

to make sure your `$.post` is actually getting a valid URL.

Then try changing your `insert_build` function to just print out what it's receiving.  You shouldn't be calling `$this->input->post(dat);` because you won't have a post named `dat`.

```
public function insert_build()
{
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

**EDIT**

You'll need to pass the json string as a url param.  Try

```
$.post(frm.attr("action"), {data:dat}, function(response) 
    {  
        alert(response);
    });
```

And then changing your PHP to

```
public function insert_build()
{    
    $str_id = $this->input->post('data');
    print_r(json_decode($str_id));
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The action was pointing to a URL with two slashes (//), although even after fixing this error, it still returns and empty array with "print_r($_POST);

Comment: I assumed it might have to do with the "stringify" in the ajax.  When I removed that, the submission returned the values I was looking for.  Any explanation why would be very helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

why not use the $.ajax?

```
$('#buildForm').live('click', function(event){
 var data = $('form[name="buildForm"]').serialize();
  $.ajax({
         url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>ajax',
         data:data,
         type:'post',
         success:function(result){
            alert(result);
         },
         error:function(result){
            alert(result);
         }
  });
});
```

hope this helps